# Cross-domain sharing session on Tomcat6.0.20

Tags: session, tomcat, cross-domain

I had a look for answers on the web. I got an answer that adds these segments in `context.xml`:

```
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".example.com" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

but unfortunately it isn't applicable for my tomcat version, so could anybody tell me how I can do this?